# I need auto suggest back!

Tags: keyboard, ios, text-input

My auto-suggest disappeared when I updated to iOS 10.3.3. How do I get it back? It was so helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places to enable it:

1. Open **Settings** → **Keyboard** and *enable* `Predictive`.
   [image]
2. With the keyboard on the screen, long-press the  key (or  if you’ve only got 1 keyboard installed) and *enable* `Predictive`.
   [image]

Comment: Personally I find predictive text very poor as it has a small vocabulary and can't always predict the words I want to use, so it remains OFF. Good answer though.

Comment: I kept it off on 4” iPhones because it just takes so much space. I also find it too slow to update to be helpful in most situations. With larger screens however I can afford the once-in-a-blue-moon instances where it comes in handy, especially for auto-completing long/difficult words